# Google charts won't load through the Jquery load function , any idea why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, jquery-load

I've asked this question before on here but no one showed me how to actually make google charts appear via the `load function`.I use google charts API and the charts display fine on a normal page .. However , when I am calling the page containing the charts code through the Jquery load function , nothing shows , but the same exact code shows on other pages .. I am required to use the load function for this , because as soon as you click on an image to compare two people , the charts have to appear from the page they're created loaded through Jquery.

Below is the google charts code that I am calling through the load function , if someone could pinpoint where the issue is , I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
//This is the compare_proc.php created the charts 

    <html> <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

            <!-- load Google AJAX API -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //load the Google Visualization API and the chart
                google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['columnchart','piechart']});

                //set callback
                google.setOnLoadCallback (createChart);

                //callback function
                function createChart() {

                    //create data table object
                    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                   //create data table object
                    var dataTableMulticolumn = new google.visualization.DataTable();


                    //define columns for first example
                    dataTable.addColumn('string','Scores');
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Results');

                    //define columns for second example
                    dataTableMulticolumn.addColumn('string','Scores');
                    dataTableMulticolumn.addColumn('number', 'Results');
                    dataTableMulticolumn.addColumn('number', 'Results');
                    dataTableMulticolumn.addColumn('number', 'Results');



                    //define rows of data for first example
                    dataTable.addRows([['Junk', 10], ['Good', 10],['Bad', 10],['Dont care', 10],['OK', 10],['Super', 10]]);

                    //define rows of data for secondf example
                    dataTableMulticolumn.addRows([['Junk',0,0,0], ['Favor',10,10,10],['DontCare',375,350,235],['BigFans', 123,100,387]]);

                    //instantiate our chart objects
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart (document.getElementById('Chart'));
                    var secondChart = new google.visualization.PieChart (document.getElementById('Chart2'));

                    //instantiate our multicolumn chart
                    var multiColumnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart (document.getElementById('Chart3'));

                    //instantiate a new chart to use as dataView Example
                    var pieChartWithView = new google.visualization.PieChart (document.getElementById('Chart4'));

                    //instantiate our Event example chart
                    var eventsChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart (document.getElementById('Chart5'));

                    //create a view of the multicolumn data table
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTableMulticolumn);

                    //filter it to get only first two columns
                    view.setColumns([0, 1]);

                    //define options for visualization
                    var options = {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true, title: 'Statistical representation of scores by opinion '};

                    //draw our chart charts
                    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
                    secondChart.draw(dataTable, options);
                    multiColumnChart.draw(dataTableMulticolumn, options);
                    pieChartWithView.draw(view, options);
                    eventsChart.draw(dataTable, options);


                   //register callbacks
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(eventsChart, 'onmouseover', showDetails);
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(eventsChart, 'onmouseout', hideDetails);

                }

                function showDetails(e) {
                    switch (e['row']) {
                        case 0: document.getElementById('details0').style.visibility='visible';
                            break;
                        case 1: document.getElementById('details1').style.visibility='visible';
                            break;
                        case 2: document.getElementById('details2').style.visibility='visible';
                            break;
                        case 3: document.getElementById('details3').style.visibility='visible';
                            break;
                    }
                }


                function hideDetails(e) {
                    switch (e['row']) {
                        case 0: document.getElementById('details0').style.visibility='hidden';
                            break;
                        case 1: document.getElementById('details1').style.visibility='hidden';
                            break;
                        case 2: document.getElementById('details2').style.visibility='hidden';
                            break;
                        case 3: document.getElementById('details3').style.visibility='hidden';
                            break;
                    }
                }


            </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="charts">
    <div id="Chart2"></div>
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

// Below is the Jquery code calling the compare_proc.php page that has the google charts code I copied above ..

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  $("#opposition a").click(function(e) {
                  var first_id  = $(this).attr('id');
                  var second_id = $("h1").attr('id');
                  $("#opposition img").mouseover(function() {
                  $(this).css('border-width','10px');
            });
                  $("#opposition img").mouseout(function() {
                  $(this).css('border-width','2px');
            });
                  $("div#test").load('compare_proc.php','id=' + first_id + '&id2=' + second_id);
                  e.preventDefault();
                    });
        });
```

Comment: jQuery `load` function may strip out scripts and head from documents it loads http://api.jquery.com/load/ If you want the document to load and run scripts you'd be better off putting it in an iframe ... or running the charting code on the jQuery page after you load compare_proc.php

Comment: Oh I see ... so load doesn't execute the scripts huh ?

Comment: @thefrontender How come load processes the PHP code though ???

Comment: `.load()` does attempt to run scripts it finds, but the problem is the scripts you're loading - jQuery, the Google visualization API, etc. - weren't written to anticipate being loaded this way. You just won't be able to get this to work this way. (But we already talked about this in your other related question, I thought?) Regarding processing the PHP code, that isn't JavaScript and `.load()` knows nothing about it. It simply requests a URL from your server and it's up to your server to run PHP or Python or Ruby or Java or whatever language you're generating your HTML/JS code in.

Comment: As we discussed previously, what you really should do is put your script code in the main page itself, not in data that you bring in with a `.load()` call. For the dynamically loaded data, have your server generate a JSON object with just the data you need, not the code. Then you can use `.getJSON()` to load that data, and do whatever you need with it from there, using the scripts that you have in the main page itself.